# Auto-Capitalization is Capitalizing First Two Letters in a Word

Tags: keyboard

This is a weird issue that has been happening with my Galaxy S5 for the past month or so (I've had it for at least 4 months, had an old one for a year before that with no issues).

This is on Android version 6.0.1 (not rooted or anything).  Often times (but not every time) when I start a new sentence in a text field, it capitalizes the first two letters of the sentence.  After the first two letters are capitalized (and I don't fix it) the word auto-corrects to an all caps version of the word (e.g. I go to type "hello" and it starts it off as "HEllo" then changes it to "HELLO").

My initial thought was that the keyboard was just lagging a bit and the "shift" key was being kept on for two letters instead of just the first.  I was paying more attention today and noticed that even if I type quite slowly, the "shift" is actually held down after the first letter goes into the textbox.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to solve this problem without turning off the Auto-capitalization or Auto-correct.  It's not a crippling issue; but it really hurts my user experience when I have to backtrack all the time.

I couldn't find anything about this online (it's a weird issue to search that gives results for things I really don't care about).  Any help fixing it or even explaining what is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm just using the stock keyboard.

Comment: What Keyboard are you using, the stock one?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that after I was away from the computer; I'll edit it in.

Comment: There is something I'm not getting: If the auto capitalization is enabled, why do you hold the shift key while taping?

Comment: @esQmo I don't hold it down.  The button is highlighted as if it was pressed (as it always does for auto-capitalization after a sentence).  The problem is that it's doing it for 2 characters instead of the first; which seems like very weird behaviour.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Did you try clearing the data and cache in the apps settings?

Comment: @esQmo yeah, I tried that yesterday and it didn't change anything.

Comment: On Android  6.0.1 : SETTINGS > APPLICATION > APPLICATIONS MANAGER > SAMSUNG KEYBOARD > STORAGE

Comment: If so, I'll just  suggest you using an alternative keyboard. Give a try  to Google Keyboard.